# how do you run a python code without the program showing in the taskbar

Tags: python

I wrote a python keylogger(dont worry im using it as a assistant and not doing illegal stuff) but I dont want the code to show in the taskbar and I want it to run in the background people have told me to use pythonw.exe but it seems that you can't retrieve the data or interact with code from pyhtonw.exe.

Let me explain what the code does everytime you press a key the key gets appended to a list and when you press the f1 button it prints the list so I have to be able to see the list when it gets printed can pythonw.exe do that?

Comment: You either have a window, or you don't have a window. If you have a window, it shows up in the taskbar. If you don't want that, you have to decide how you want to access the results. You could, for example, save the results to a file. Then, you could add an icon in the system tray, which would show a window with results...

Comment: Just send it to your email or save it to a file, but you can't see the result immediately without having a window.